# Using variable as keyword passed to **kwargs in Python

Tags: python, arguments, keyword, keyword-argument

I have a function that updates a record via an API. The API accepts a variety of optional keyword parameters:

```
def update_by_email(self, email=None, **kwargs):
    result = post(path='/do/update/email/{email}'.format(email=email), params=kwargs)
```

I have another function that uses the first function to update an individual field in the record:

```
def update_field(email=None, field=None, field_value=None):
    """Encoded parameter should be formatted as <field>=<field_value>"""
    request = update_by_email(email=email, field=field_value)
```

This doesn't work. When I call:

`update_field(email='joe@me.com', field='name', field_value='joe')`

the url is encoded as:

`https://www.example.com/api/do/update/email/joe@me.com?field=Joe`

How can I get it to encode as:

`https://www.example.com/api/do/update/email/joe@me.com?name=Joe`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rather than passing the parameter named as `field`, you can use dictionary unpacking to use the *value of* `field` as the name of the parameter:

```
request = update_by_email(email, **{field: field_value})
```

Using a mock of `update_by_email`:

```
def update_by_email(email=None, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
```

When I call

```
update_field("joe@me.com", "name", "joe")
```

I see that `kwargs` inside `update_by_email` is

```
{'name': 'joe'}
```